# Why is ST_X and ST_Y of recently inserted GEOGRAPHY(Point) for certain coordinates different than value inserted?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, sql

I have a table of cities that includes the name and location of that city.

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name        varchar (255),
    location    GEOGRAPHY(Point)
)
```

For certain cities, I'll set the location:

```
UPDATE cities SET location='POINT(32.4543 -99.7384)' WHERE slug='abilene';
```

But when I retrieve the longitude and latitude for that location, it is different than the value I inserted:

```
select ST_X(location::geometry),ST_Y(location::geometry) from cities where slug='abilene'
```

The ST_X is correct at **32.4543** but the ST_Y is incorrect at **-80.2616**

Why is the latitude different than the value I inserted?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.9 and Postgis 2.5

Comment: Read https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography: `If you do not specify an SRID, the SRID will default to 4326 WGS 84 long/lat will be used, and all calculations will proceed using WGS84.` Latitude can't be -99.7384.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coordinates must be expressed as longitude first, then latitude.

Instead of throwing an error when PostGIS receive a latitude of -99 degrees, it makes some artistic computation to try to locate the point on the earth surface (like going on the other side of the pole).

--> fix your coordinates order